# Executing WP-CLI via SSH and Capistrano

Tags: wordpress, ssh, capistrano

I am fairly new to cap hence I can't figure out one thing.

I have wp-cli installed on my server which I can run with `wp` ie `wp --vetsion` directly on the server will output WP-CLI 0.19.1 - great.

What I am trying to achieve is run the command  with Capistrano

```
namespace :test do
    desc "Show WP-CLI version"
    task :dosomething do
          run "cd #{release_path} && wp --version"
    end
end
```

Unfortunately it is returning the following error :

```
sh: wp: command not found
```

Im not sure where I am going wrong.

Any help much appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSH into your server and run `which wp` or `find /home/yourusername/ -name 'wp'` to find out where wp-cli is located.

Let's say wp-cli is located under your home path in bin folder, then you would add `run "cd #{release_path} && /home/yourusername/bin/wp --version"`. I hope this helps.